# String not working in visual studio c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am a newbie in in C++, I write a header file in which I define a class 'Person' in which I define a Constructor 'Person' having a string type argument and a modifier 'Print'. In my main program I pass a string to constructor 'Person', and then I call modifier print, which prints the string that I have passed to constructor.Now the problem is when I compile this code it shows this error:-

Error   3   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   d:\c++\inaheritance\inaheritance\person.h   7
Error   4   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   d:\c++\inaheritance\inaheritance\person.h   7
Error   9   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   d:\c++\inaheritance\inaheritance\person.h   7
Error   10  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   d:\c++\inaheritance\inaheritance\person.h   7

But when I change constructor argument into integer type , my code runs fine.
So please tell me how to use string.
here is my code

```
// Person.h------>>>
class Person
{
    public:
        Person (string stName);
        virtual void Print() const;
    private:
    string m_stName;
};


//Person.cpp----->>>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
#include"Person.h"

Person::Person(string stName)
    :m_stName(stName)
{
    //empty
}
void Person::Print(void) const
{
    cout << m_stName << endl;
}


//main.cpp---->>>
#include<iostream>
#include"Person.h"
#include"subclass.h"
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
void main(void)
{
    Person person(1);
    person.Print();
    getch();
}
```

Comment: You need to include `<string>` in the header, and refer to it as `std::string`.

Comment: thanks  juanchopanza , its working now